# jquery form validate

Tags: jquery

How can I input in the textbox and only accept numbers and symbols without use maskedinput?

eg :  12345-12

Answer (score 1):

You might try this approach:
[How to allow only numeric (0-9) in HTML  inputbox using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery)

Or perhaps:
http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/04/textbox-accept-only-numbers-digits.html

Answer (score 0):

use a validation library and tweak the regex so that it matches what you want.
i like [this library](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/). :)

Comment: hw to validate the date ? eg 900907  the frst 90 is year ,09 month n 07 is day... tq

Answer (score 0):

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation